# How to allow edit the attribute e.g. color, size when checkout in PrestaShop?

Tags: javascript, php, html, prestashop

I am creating an ecommerce shop using PrestaShop.

When the user is in checkout:

[image]

Are there any module / modification can achieve allow the user select another attribute e.g. color, size during checkout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I quickly found this:

- [PrestaShop Checkout Custom Fields](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/315353-module-prestashop-checkout-custom-fields/) "used to add custom fields such as Text Area, Text field, date, multi-select, yes/no, dropdown, message only, checkbox and radio buttons on checkout pages".
- [PrestaShop Order Attributes Addon](https://sourceforge.net/projects/prestashoporderattributesaddon/). "This FMM custom checkout attributes module creates tabs on order page."
- [FME modules: Custom fields](http://www.fmemodules.com/en/51-custom-fields.html) "Add new fields on PrestaShop checkout page easily by using FMM custom checkout attributes module."

(I don't have any experience with using these.)

Comment: thanks a lot for helping. unfortunately it is adding extra input instead of changing the purchase product

Comment: I think these modules can do what you ask in your question. Otherwise, please be more specific in your question.

Comment: sorry for confusing you, the main aim is to allow the user change different choice e.g. they select the yellow shirt before, but want to change to red shirt during checkout. so it is not extra field , thanks for your great effort anyway